# Coding with Dojo, received error 'dijit.byId(...)' is null or not an object

Tags: dojo

I see many references to this error on the web, but they are not helping me.  I guess i am new enough to this that i need a specific answer for my problem.
     I am attaching the first portion of code on a page that i am running.  the last line i show is the line that is creating the error stating in the title.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <title>CDI Web Portal</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
   <script src="js\dojo\dojo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAA5a4NhilcmrdMQ5e3o22QWRQWrGbhbxAguaJ-a4SLWYiya7Z2NRTDfQBdxmHdf5ydkZYLZTiz1tDXfg"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ge-poly-fit-hack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="kmldomwalk.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    @import "js/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css";
    @import "js/dojo/resources/dojo.css";
  </style>
  <style type="text/css">@import "index.css";</style>

    <script type="text/javascript"> dojo.ready(function() { dojo.byId("greeting").innerHTML += ", from " + dojo.version; });     </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[

    djConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };
   // google.load("dojo", "1.6.1");
    google.load("maps", "2");
    google.load("earth", "1");

    var g_ge;
    var g_earthDisabled = false;
    var g_kmlObject;

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        dojo.require('dijit.layout.BorderContainer');
        dojo.require('dijit.layout.SplitContainer');
        dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
        dojo.require('dijit.Tree');
        //dojo.require('CheckboxTree');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.CheckBox');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.Button');
        dojo.require('dijit.form.TextBox');
        dojo.require('dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore');
        dojo.require('dojo.parser');
        dojo.require('dojo.cookie');
        dojo.require('dojo.fx');
        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
            // load checkboxtree
            var scpt = document.createElement('script');
            scpt.src = "dijit.CheckboxTree.js";
            document.body.appendChild(scpt);

            { dijit.byId('load-button').setDisabled(true) };
            // build earth
            google.earth.createInstance(
      'map3d',
      function(ge) {
          g_ge = ge;
          g_ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
          g_ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_AUTO);
          g_ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(g_ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);
          g_ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(g_ge.LAYER_BUILDINGS, true);

          dijit.byId('load-button').setDisabled(false);
          checkAutoload();
      },
      function() {
          g_earthDisabled = true;
          dijit.byId('load-button').setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment, you used declarative syntax to create the dijit, i.e. `<button id="load-button" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="loadKml();">`. If the declarative syntax is used, the dijit is actually created after the page is loaded. So you should put the code to use the dijit in the Dojo's load callback, i.e. inside of `dojo.addOnLoad` callback.

But your code is bad formatted and mingled with Google Maps load callback, it's not easy to inspect the code. My suggestion would be to wrap the `dijit.byId('load-button').setDisabled(true);` with `dojo.addOnLoad`, like below:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    dijit.byId('load-button').setDisabled(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you've got a dojo object rather than a dijit object -- or possibly no object named `load-button` at all, since it's not clear from this where `load-button` is being created.  Make sure there is an object with `id="load-button"` that was created with dijit.

Comment: Thank you.  I know you have the answer, it is just not clear to me yet what i need to do.  Here is a copy of the code in the body of my page. Here you will see my reference to the load-button.                                                    
      <button id="load-button" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="loadKml();">